# C# MetroTile backcolor/forecolor not changing during mouse enter/leave

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using the Win Form Metro Framework in VS 2015 to build a Metro Form with Metro Tiles in Windows 7. When a mouse enters a metro Tile I want the backcolor and forecolor to change and when the mouse leaves, change back. However, it's not working. Nothing happens and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In the Form1.cs(Design) file I have set the following properties of all tiles to the following:

```
BackColor = White
ForeColor = Black
Name = caseCompassDevo
CustomBackground = True
CustomForeColor = True
```

in the Form1.Designer.cs file I have the following code in the  InitializeComponent() method:

```
// caseCompassDevo
        // 
        this.caseCompassDevo.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.caseCompassDevo.CustomBackground = true;
        this.caseCompassDevo.CustomForeColor = true;
        this.caseCompassDevo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.caseCompassDevo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 92);
        this.caseCompassDevo.Name = "caseCompassDevo";
        this.caseCompassDevo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(149, 87);
        this.caseCompassDevo.TabIndex = 0;
        this.caseCompassDevo.Text = "Case Compass DEVO";
        this.caseCompassDevo.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.caseCompassDevo.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.caseCompassDevo_Click);
        this.caseCompassDevo.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.caseCompassDevo_MouseEnter);
        this.caseCompassDevo.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.caseCompassDevo_MouseLeave);
//
```

in my Form1.cs file I have added the following events:

```
namespace Links
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void caseCompassDevo_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 174, 219); //MetroUI blue
            ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255); //white
        }

        private void caseCompassDevo_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255); //white
            ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);  //black
        }       

        private void caseCompassDevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //private void caseCompassTest_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your sure your applying your colour to the tile. It looks like your applying it to the form it self. Can't you try caseCompassDevo.BackColor =   Color.Green;

Comment: @TimonPost it's being applied to the caseCompassDevo MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTile Property

Comment: @TimonPost - I missed the last part of of your answer. That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should apply it to your `caseCompassDevo`. use BackColor property of caseCompassDevo and assign your appropriate color to that.